# substring with perl (Regex?)

Tags: perl

I need help to extract "BODY" part from string according to the two following cases:

Case 1:

```
Var1 = 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

BODY 

--000000000000ddc1610580816add


Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

BODY56 text/html

--000000000000ddc1610580816add-
```

Case 2:

```
Var1=
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

BODY

--000000000000ddc1610580816add--



Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

BODY56 text/html

--000000000000ddc1610580816add-
```

I want to do:

if Var1 contains: 
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"`
 then 
extract text between 
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"` 
and 
`--000000000000ddc1610580816add`

else if Var1 contains:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Then extract text between:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And `--000000000000ddc1610580816add--`.

my Code, I need to fix it if someone can fix it:

```
 if (index($body, "Content-Type: text\/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable") != -1) {
    $body =~ /Content-Type: text\/plain; charset="UTF-8"\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable(.*?)--00.*/s ;
                        $body=$1;

}
    elsif   (index($body, "Content-Type: text\/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"") != -1)
                              {
    $body =~ /Content-Type: text\/plain; charset="UTF-8"(.*?)--00.*/s ;
                        $body=$1;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet yourself? It looks like you are trying to parse a MIME encoded multi-part document. There are modules for this on CPAN. Doing it yourself is a bit mad.

Comment: I have tried several times, and I always do, I'm not strong in regex, for now the need is to use the regex because I've already used Mail :: IMAPClient (function: bodypart_string) and using the regex I can arrive at the expected results, it remains for me just this part which requires the use of regex

Comment: An IMAP Client is something else. You want to parse email bodies, not download email.

Comment: I recommend [Email::MIME](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME).

Comment: thank you Simbabque and Grinnz, Email::MIME is a good idea, 
I managed to extract only the text / plain from body by using Email::MIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution: use `/ms` modifier, see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = qr/\AContent-Type: [^\n]+\n(?:^Content-Transfer-Encoding: [^\n]+\n)?(.+)^--.+\Z/ms;
my $body;

my $input = <<'END_OF_STRING';
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

INPUT 1 BODY

--000000000000ddc1610580816add--
END_OF_STRING

($body) = ($input =~ $regex)
    or die "mismatch in INPUT 1!\n";
print "INPUT 1 '${body}'\n";

$input = <<'END_OF_STRING';
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

INPUT 2 BODY

--000000000000ddc1610580816add--
END_OF_STRING

($body) = ($input =~ $regex)
    or die "mismatch in INPUT 2!\n";
print "INPUT 2 '${body}'\n";

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
INPUT 1 '
INPUT 1 BODY

'
INPUT 2 '
INPUT 2 BODY

'
```

**UPDATE:** with the new input string provided by OP:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# multipart MIME content as single string
my $input = <<'END_OF_STRING';
--0000000000007bcdff05808169f5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

BODY text/plain

--0000000000007bcdff05808169f5
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

BODY text/html

--0000000000007bcdff05808169f5
END_OF_STRING

# split into multiple parts at the separator
foreach my $part (split(/^--[^\n]+\n/ms, $input)) {
    # skip empty parts
    next if $part =~ /\A\s*\Z/m;

    # split header and body
    my($header, $body) = split("\n\n", $part, 2);

    # Only match parts with text/plain content
    # "Content-Type" must be matched case-insensitive
    if ($header =~ m{^(?i)Content-Type(?-i):\s+text/plain[;\s]}ms) {
        print "plain text BODY: '${body}'\n";
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Test output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
plain text BODY: 'BODY text/plain

'
```

Comment: I want to extract only the body (without --000000...) , 
I want a body extraction according to both cases , the header of Var1 can be: Content-Type: text / plain; charset = "UTF-8" or Content-Type: text / plain; charset = "UTF-8 "
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your comment. My answer shows the desired output shown in your question. I have updated my answer to include both input texts, maybe it becomes more clear now?

Comment: @Red_Developper updated with your latest input string. That makes things much simpler, BTW.